# Can I use the verb ‘to calculate with’ in a given example?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, british-english

Boiler size **is calculated with sufficient reserve** for the number of beds in a particular apartment.

Comment: I believe the sentence is well formed, but whether it is really correct depends on the meaning you are seeking to convey ... which you haven't given us any further means of ascertaining. My guesses are that this is a context where you are speaking of calculating what size of boiler _should be_ installed somewhere, but the intent of "sufficient reserve" is less clear. If you are happy that your audience will understand that portion, then I believe your sentence is fine as it stands, but if not you'll have to provide more detail to get better responses here.

Comment: This is just information for guests in a hotel not to be afraid of lack of hot tap water. The meaning is that ‘Boilers are big enough to ensure a sufficient amount of hot water for each room they stay in.’

Comment: I'm not sure your sentence conveys that very clearly. Perhaps "Based on typical usage, our boilers have sufficient reserve to supply the daily hot water needs for the number of beds in your apartment." However, if I was a guest,  I'd want to know what happens next ... will water be heated "on demand" or must they wait until the boiler fires up on it's next duty cycle?

Comment: the following part is: If you run out of hot water, reheating of the entire boiler volume takes 2.5 hours.

Comment: Each apartment has a boiler?  Not a hot water heater?  And it only reheats when the supply is exhausted?  How many beds might an apartment have?

Comment: I’m confused.. I thought a bolier and a hot water heater are synonyms ... BTW, Each apartment has a hot water heater which reheats when the supply is exhausted. But there is also a hot water storage tank for all the apartments. So guests are not supposed to wait while water is again reheated but water is drawn from the tank.

Comment: Water is heated in a hot water heater in each apartment or studio, or in the central hot water storage tank.

Comment: Our boilers have sufficient reserves for the number of beds in a particular apartment. Calculate is not properly collocated here. You are not "calculating" a boiler size, you are determining what size of boiler an apartment needs....

Answer (score 1):

I'm still fairly new here on ELU, so I'm not entirely sure this question is [on topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, based on the comments, I'd suggest something like the following form of words:

> Based on typical usage, our boilers should comfortably fulfil the hot water needs of all those staying in your apartment. Should you run out of hot water, reheating the entire boiler will take approximately 2 ½ hours.

Comment: Your version is vague compared to the original. It reveals no information as to whether there are reserves. I'm not saying it's wrong, but it's not equivalent to OP's intended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

> Boiler size is calculated with sufficient reserves [..] **in mind**.

This is correct. However, I'm not sure if it is grammatically correct to omit "in mind".

> Boiler size is calculated with sufficient reserves [..].

It sounds less correct; but that doesn't say anything about its grammatical correctness.

According to [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/calculate) (which may not be an accepted source here, I'm not sure), one of the definitions inherently means you have something in mind, though it is considered dialect:

> **Calculate**
>
> transitive verb
>   -·lat·ed, -·lat·ing
>
> - to determine by using mathematics; compute
> - to reckon or determine by reasoning, evaluating, etc.; estimate; judge
> - to plan or intend for a purpose: a tale calculated to mislead us
> - (dialect) to think, suppose, guess, etc.
> - (dialect) **to have in mind** (to go, do, etc.); intend

Assuming the correctness of that definition, I would say it is correct to omit "in mind".